# Listview not detect on click when the textview has set to be selectable

Tags: android, listview, onclick, click

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Log.d("test1","run");
    }
});
```

The listview is not fire , if I set like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
```

After I remove the textIsSelectable, the onitemclicklistener is fired.

I have studied a while, and I followed some suggestion on the internet

e.g.

put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to parent view

The clicklistener is fired this time , but when select the text it show error:

```
TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.
```

Can both function exist? thanks a lot

Comment: try rebuilding your app

Comment: thanks for reply, no luck still the same error: TextView does not support text selection. Selection cancelled.

Comment: This `TextView` is "stealing" the event. I'd use `RecyclerView` instead, so you can manage this easily.